# How I can distribute values in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Regards.

Can you help me with the following?
I have the following records:

```
**ITEM VALUES**
A001 29440
A002 29440
A003 29440
A004 29440
A005 29440
```

Σ of the field values is equal to 147200, but the real value is 148 200.
How I can distribute each value in the VALUES column for the Σ is exactly equal to 148 200.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish with better examples. Why do you say the real value is 148200?

Comment: Add 200 to each value?

Comment: Hi. TheMadDBA
The REAL value is given by the total bill and the value of the items are the values of the products.
Due to differences in rounding the items values, the difference occurs with the REAL value.
There will be some way to distribute the REAL value in each value of items for which the Σ of the EACH RECORD is exactly like the REAL value.

Comment: Hi  MT0. Yes, i need something like that.

Comment: Is there a linked table that has the 'real' total value, that you can join to wherever these item values are? Will the item values always be the same, and if not do you want to adjust them all by the same amount, or proportionally? Do you want to update the item values or just adjust them as you query? (Perhaps you should be focusing on why they are wrong though, and fixing your - rather large - rounding error)

Answer (score 0):

Without a better guide as to how you got the "real" value and how the difference should be distributed, you could do something trivial to fix the data - such as adding an equal share of the difference to each value.

Like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac12d1/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( ITEM, VALUE ) AS
          SELECT 'A001', 29440 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'A002', 29440 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'A003', 29440 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'A004', 29440 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'A005', 29440 FROM DUAL;

UPDATE TEST
SET VALUE = VALUE + ( SELECT (148200 - SUM( VALUE ))/COUNT(1) FROM TEST );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac12d1/1/0)**:

```
| ITEM | VALUE |
|------|-------|
| A001 | 29640 |
| A002 | 29640 |
| A003 | 29640 |
| A004 | 29640 |
| A005 | 29640 |
```